# Jquery How add script in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day.

Im sorry if answer already exist but i didnt find answer.

I have script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" 
src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?
sid=zlmO6Je7xDJz1L7TRRaR7ILinfHiVTtD&width=600&height=450">
</script>
```

Me need ad him in div.

Fr it i use code:

```
 $('.WhereBuyRegionsYandexMap').html('
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" 
src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?sid=zlmO6Je7xDJz1L7TRRaR7ILinfHiVTtD&width=600&height=450">
</script>');
```

But it not work.

ITell me please have aright add script in div(use jquery)?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `\` before `/script`

OR

```
var str='<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" 
src="//api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?sid=zlmO6Je7xDJz1L7TRRaR7ILinfHiVTtD&width=600&height=450">
';
str+="<";
str+="/script>";

$('.WhereBuyRegionsYandexMap').append(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

don't know what you want to achieve 
but to get a script using jquery you use `$.getScript` 
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
      $.getScript('//api-maps.yandex.ru/services/constructor/1.0/js/?sid=zlmO6Je7xDJz1L7TRRaR7ILinfHiVTtD&width=600&height=450')
          .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
               console.log( textStatus );
          })
          .fail(function( jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
                $( "div.log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
          });
    });
});
```

something like that should give you a start

`$.getScript` Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

Comment: script lo yanex map on site. i want make load map when i click on link

Comment: `$.getScript` is your answer definitely check the answer I added some codes for you

Answer (score 0):

Use of jquery's innerHTML or append function

```
<div id ="content"></div>

<script>
  var url = 'http://www.google.com';
  $(document).ready( function() {
      $("#content").innerHTML(url); //OR
      $("#content").append(url);
  });
</script>
```